# Prerender.io: "angular.js:14525 TypeError: Cannot set property 'seo' of undefined"

Tags: angularjs, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api, prerender

**EDIT** I seem to have solved my problem, as I'm not getting the error anymore.

I realized there was a lot of junk in this controller that I was no longer using, so I got rid of it, and also removed `var vm = this;`, and replaced all instances of `vm` with `$scope`.

**Updated Code**

```
(function () {

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('screeningsController', Controller);

function Controller($scope) {
    //var vm = this;

    $scope.seo = { 
        metaTitle : '', metaDescription : '' 
        }; 

    $scope.$parent.seo = { 
        metaTitle : 'Screenings', 
        metaDescripton: 'A list of all upcoming screenings for films.' 
        }; 

    }
}

)();
```

I'm having trouble implementing [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/), and I've been getting the error `angular.js:14525 TypeError: Cannot set property 'seo' of undefined` in the browser console.

I've been following along with this [Scotch.io article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-seo-with-prerender-io). I'm not really seeing where `seo` is "defined" in the code from the article. Here is the code I've incorporated from this article thus far:

**index.html  tag**

```
<!--prerender.io & SEO-->
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
<meta name="url" content="{{ seo.metaUrl }}">
<meta name="title" content="{{ seo.metaTitle }}">
<meta name="description" content="{{ seo.metaDescription }}">
<meta name="image" content="{{ seo.metaImage }}">
```

**angular.js controller**

```
(function () {

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('screeningsController', Controller);

function Controller(ModalService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.seo = { 
        metaTitle : '', metaDescription : '' 
        }; 

    vm.$parent.seo = { 
        metaTitle : 'Screenings', 
        metaDescripton: 'A list of all upcoming screenings for films.' 
        }; 

    //the rest of this code works fine
    vm.openModal = openModal;
    vm.closeModal = closeModal;

    function openModal(id){
        ModalService.Open(id);
    }

    function closeModal(id){
        ModalService.Close(id);
    }
}

})();
```

On a more general note, is this the most "modern" way of getting meta tags to work with Facebook? [The Google article discussing AJAX Crawling that is linked to from the Scotch.io page says that this has been deprecated since October 2015.](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more)